# MPI parallel program execution on single computer

Tags: c++, mpi

I want to run parallel codes on single pc with core i7 cpu I can compile my code but I have problem with running it.

I compile my code with mpicxx and when I run it by " mpirun -np 8 ./a.out" only one process is. My operating system is linux ubuntu 11.04.

Working what must I do?

For example I want to run this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int mynode, totalnodes;
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &totalnodes);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mynode);
    cout << "Hello world from process " << mynode;
    cout << " of " << totalnodes << endl;
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

I use mpich2 with mpirun --version:1.3.1

Comment: you should tell us what version of MPI you are running.

Comment: Also what VERSION of mpich2 you are using. They changed process manager from MPD to Hydra between version 1.2 and 1.3, so details about how to launch a parallel application changes. You can see it running mpirun --version.

Comment: "Suppose"? Meh, you have this problem on your particular version. In the latest version, you should use mpiexec and a properly-defined machinefile.

Comment: There are some alternatives: you can use a backport, grab the latest package from the "experimental" branch of your distribution and install it by hand or by configuring the package manager or, simply, you compile it from the distribution source package. However, this is a question which should be posed individually and, maybe, in a different Q&A site.

Comment: What _exactly_ happens when you try to run it as above?

Comment: if your trying to Print Hello world from each core this will not work

Comment: also your using the C syntax of MPI , there is also C++ syntax as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use ubuntu operating system you can execute your codes with mpiexec -n 8 /path/to/application too and no machine file is required just be sure that you installed mpich library properly for doing this you can use synaptic package manager for installing library.

Answer (score 2):

In your mpich2 version, it is encouraged to use mpiexec in lieu of mpirun.

To launch an application, you should write a machinefile with this syntax:

```
machine1[:number of cores]
...
machinen[:number of cores]
```

One line for each machine, with optionally the number of cores preceded by a colon, example:

```
node0:2
node1:3
```

You invoke then your application like that:

```
mpiexec -f machinefile -n <number of processes> yourapplication
```

Try it and tell us what you get.

Remember that, in the default configuration, mpich2 requires a loginless ssh configuration in order to launch the processes.

Comment: I dont know how can I write machine file

Comment: For your simple case, you want a file named `machinefile` with the single line `localhost:8`. Then run `mpiexec -f machinefile -n 8 /path/to/application arguments`.

Comment: now I have compile problem .the error is usr/bin/ld :cannot find -lcr collect2:ld returned 1 exit status process manager worked but compiler now do not work!

Comment: this is a Q&A site, not a "we make your stuff work" one. Ask each question separately.